# ELSE IF Condition in Ampscript

Tags: ampscript, conditional

I'm working on a cloud page where i would like to use an `ELSE IF` condition instead of two `IF` conditions. Does any one know a syntax for `ELSE IF`

Below is my current Ampscript code. These are captured from Form submission via *HTTP POST* . I don't think that code is necessary here, But if it helps I'm more than happy to add it to the question!

```
%%[
var @campaignMemberRows, @initialResp, @finalResp

set @initialResp = RequestParameter('Attendance')

/* Capturing accepted status */
IF @initialResp == "Accept" THEN
set @finalResp = "Accepted"
ENDIF

/* Capturing Declined status */
IF @initialResp == "Decline" THEN
set @finalResp = "Declined"
ENDIF

]%%
```

What I'm rather wanting to do is something like below!(This code just doesn't set the values and doesn't throw any error either)

```
%%[
/* Capturing accepted status */
IF @initialResp == "Accept" THEN
set @finalResp = "Accepted"

/* Capturing Declined status */
ELSE IF @initialResp == "Decline" THEN
set @finalResp = "Declined"
ENDELSEIF

]%%
```

> NOTE: I'm not looking for `IF ELSE` condition as there might be more
>   than a couple of responses I might want to capture so I'm specifically
>   looking for `ELSE IF` condition.

Comment: have you looked at ternaries i.e IIF?

Comment: also change this `ENDELSEIF` to `ENDIF`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your end statement should just be

"endif"

That would work [IF Syntax here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)

Comment: That looks simple and it worked ! Thanks, only thing is i haven't seen an example with else if so unsure of what goes in the end!

Comment: Link I provided in answer has a example in the "Using IF Syntax" section